# How can I fix `Failed to import the required Python library (botocore or boto3)` with ansible on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ansible

I am usually able to resolve this problem with specifying `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3`

Despite using `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` in Amazon Linux 2 (cloud9), I still get errors when trying to run the following playbook on Amazon Linux 2.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: "{{ variable_gather_facts | default('false') }}"
  become: true
  any_errors_fatal: true

  tasks:
  - name: "Create a role and attach a managed policy called 'aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role'"
    community.aws.iam_role:
      name: aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role
      assume_role_policy_document: "{{ lookup('file','policy.json') }}"
      managed_policies:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole
    vars:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Create a role and attach a managed policy called 'aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role'] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false
}

MSG:

Failed to import the required Python library (botocore or boto3) on ip-172-31-28-167.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
```

I have installed those packages using this method, so it is unclear why the error above is occuring:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip 
python3 -m pip install ansible boto3 botocore
```

I can also verify that when running python I can import both those libraries

Additionally here is some more useful info:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.10.7
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.9 (default, Feb 18 2021, 03:10:35) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12)]
```

Comment: The package needs to be installed on the target. This can be fixed by adding the following task (oneliner because in comment...): `{name: "Make sure boto is installed", pip: {name: ['boto3', 'bobocore']}}`

Comment: I have done this but it does not work.

Comment: I see in your question your attempts to install manually the libs on localhost using the `python3` binary that is found somewhere in your interactive session path. I don't see any attempts to install those on `ip-172-31-28-167.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal` using the exact python version `/usr/bin/python3` or to make sure the libs were actually installed there (which is obviously not the case from your error message).